# Using Pidgin 2.5.2 in Linux no sound is made for incoming messages (as it should)

Tags: linux, pidgin

I have a problem with Pidgin 2.5.2 in Linux (Ubuntu 8.10). When someone sends me a message no sound is played (the tray indicates a new message and  blinks, that's it).

Sounds play fine when I send someone a message. If I preview the *Message received* and *Message sent* sound events both of them do make a sound. Automatic and ALSA is what's working from the alternatives in Sound method selection.

I include a screenshot containing a lot of relevant information:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What does this mean: "Automatic and ALSO is what's working from the alternatives in Sound method selection."

Comment: You probably mean ALSA (Advanced Linux Sound Architecture) and not ALSO?

Comment: Yes I did, I meant ALSA. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Did you try moving to a newer or older version of Pidgin? Maybe you could enable the Pidgin PPA and try out the latest version?

Comment: I'm installing 9.04 instead of 8.04 of Xubuntu in a moment. But I already used the backported version which is available in 9.04. So yes, I've tried a newer version, but not the latest one. I'll definitely check out Pidgin PPA.

Comment: The fact that you can make Pidgin produce sounds in some cases pretty solidly rules out audio configuration issues, so if after trying other versions of Pidgin you still have no luck, your best bet may be Pidgin's bug reporting (http://developer.pidgin.im/).

Answer (score 1):

I was using pidgin in Kubuntu 8.10, and I tried a lot, but I gaved up..  I used pidgin without sound.

now I'm using Kubuntu 9.10 (just because I found the karmic version, so it is possible to have kubuntu 9.10 with kde3.5, because for me.. I would never leave 8.10 version. I really don't like kde4)

anyway... in kubuntu9.10, the sound is working properly.

what I just can't do here, is to find a way to play sounds even when I'm listening to mp3 or videos. (in windows I also use pidgin, and its sounds work when listening to mp3s or watching videos)

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of adding my profile information over and over and gave up Pidgin for [Meebo](http://www.meebo.com/).

Comment: I'm reluctant to use a on-line service for all my IM'ing. But it looks like a nice service.

Comment: Recommending http://imo.im too, has Skype too.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Never mind, I missed the very faint check mark where it is, in fact, supposed to be.

In your screenshot, it looks like you have some of the sounds unchecked. Notice the "Play" column. Try checking some of those boxes and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Well the Message received column is checked. And so is my Message Sent column, and I do hear sounds when I send a message.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The check mark is really really faint.